# What do internet-constructions like "Me seeing real couples" mean?

Tags: grammar, internet

I often see a lot of people on the internet using such constructions:

> *Me seeing real couples.*

It's incorrect grammar but I don't know why they use it so much. What exactly does it mean? Can someone explain this? (I have been learning English for 2 months.)

Comment: It's not grammatically valid.

Comment: This question should be on ELL and not here. That said, please look up: gerunds. That said, your phrase is like a title as it does not contain a predicate. Me seeing you yesterday *was* fun.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on ELL.

Comment: @Lambie The asker is a learner but this is something a native speaker might well ask also.

Comment: @alphabet ELU is intended for linguists and the sister site was set up for more basic questions. You don't have to be a non-native speaker to use ELL.

Comment: It's an ACC-ing structure, most often seen in sentences such as 'Can you imagine me seeing a real tiger?' / 'I can't understand him trying to get on the first eleven' but also used as subject ('Him seeing a tiger would be something many would find amusing.'

Answer (score 6):

In the absence of any further context, this style is often accompanied by an image that reflects how the writer feels in a particular situation.
I would interpret "Me seeing real couples" as a shorthand for "This is an image of me seeing real couples".
The image chosen by the writer might be of a person (usually not themselves) or animal looking surprised, disgusted, happy or some other emotion but in an exaggerated way.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @[Leachoid's](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/447929/leachoid) [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/612547/466641), we often see this kind of style used in ***[memes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_meme)***. In memes, you do have a slight limit in terms of space, so—like in headlines—we delete words that are extraneous or unnecessary.

The full sentence, obviously, would be:

> [This is] me seeing real couples.

As with captions, which is what meme-text really is, you don't *need* the 'this is' part- because the text is already right next to the image that you're describing.

> > [image]
>
> > [image]